# iOS Add ScrollView to an existing View

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, uiscrollview

I have a View in a `ViewController` which contains 3 `TableView`s. I have to add 1 more TableView at bottom. Everything doesn't fit in a single screen size, hence now I have to make the screen scrollable.

I searched around, but don't get how to add scrollview, what would be best -

1. should I make the View (UIView) as ScrollView.
2. Should add a ScrollView in the View and add all TableView's in sCrollView
3. Any other better way to implement the same.

I also need to make my TableView's scrollable, so I guess need to add ScrollView's to them too respectively.

What would be best and preferred way of implementing Scrolling to View & TableView's respectively? MY layout is in StoryBoard.

Comment: view >> scrollview >> 3 table views... but we should not mix uiscrollview and uitableview usually...

Comment: @FahimParkar, then how to make a TableView scrollable ?

Comment: tableview are auto-scrollable... we don't write code for tableview to scroll...

Comment: @FahimParkar, How do I make my view scrollable ? Contents of view are mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have posted my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I would say follow below steps.

1. Add UIScrollView
2. Let's say you have 3 table view each of height 300.
3. Add those three table view in scrollview on position as below.

   UITableView1 >> `tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);` `[myScrollView addSubView:tableView1];`

   UITableView2 >> `tableView2.frame = CGRectMake(0,300,320,300);` `[myScrollView addSubView:tableView2];`

   UITableView3 >> `tableView3.frame = CGRectMake(0,600,320,300);` `[myScrollView addSubView:tableView3];`
4. Now set ContentSize of UIScrollView as below.

   `myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,900);`

If still scrollview is not scrollable, put `myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,900);` in viewDidAppear

```
- (void) viewDidAppear {
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,900);
}
```

This way you will have scrollview scrollable of height 900px.

**Hope this is what you was looking for.**